# moving static block 'out of container'

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

I am currently using Magento 1.9 and the Bootstrap boilerplate.

I have already put the banner slider in a static block.

Is there any way to move a static block out of the container to below the menu?

So it fits the screen width wise.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create some static block, then put your code on it.

2) To display this block out of container and after the menu in **All pages**, you have to add this piece of code in : `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml`

The piece of code:

```
<default>
...
<reference name="top.container">
    <block type="cms/block" name="custom.slider" after="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_id</block_id></action>
    </block> 
</reference>
...
</default>
```

Clean Magento and browser cache.

Comment: you're welcome !